Hadith about Gathering in the womb for 40 days
There is a famous hadith about embroy in womb mentioning alaqa,mudgah and nutfa stage.Ref:bukhari 3208.Here in this hadith it states"إِنَّ أَحَدَكُمْ يُجْمَعُ خَلْقُهُ فِي بَطْنِ أُمِّهِ أَرْبَعِينَ يَوْمًا، " and translation is "Creation of each of you is put together in the womb for 40 days".I know some scholars say that  alaqa,Mudgah and nutfa all happen in the 40 days it is not 120 days. Interpretation of 40 days is acurate according to modern science.But my question is how can we explain the Gathering of Creation in Womb for 40 days?what is actually gathered in the womb if we interpret the hadith in a way that all stages take place in the same 40 days not individually 40 days?

It pretty much saying: before the embryob gets it's shape and soul gets breath into the embryo it gathers in the womb.
From scientific perspective one can say: this when all the precursor cells that will develop into bones or muscles or skin etc migrate throughout the embryonic body.
Another hadith in sahih Muslim says: after 42 nights passed, Allah send an angel to shape and create the embryo: sights, hearing, skin, bone, muscles......
Scientifically major transformation takes in embryo from end of week 6th of development which is 42 days.
Bone ossification starts around that time, musclefibers starts to form at that time, retina starts to form at that time, spiral corti (responsible for hearing) start to from that time, skin stem cells in basel layers froms at week 8 after day 42. Etc... embryo starts looking like human from day 44. Etc...
So gathering hear can mean that it's getting prepared for the angel that Allah will send and the angel will shape and create the embryo.
Hope this answers the question. If you need reference for the medical stuff let me know, I will give you reference to them.
Allah knows best!!!!

Yes Thank you.And if you can please give me reference as you have promised

Grays anatomy 42nd edition: page 762, tells you about muscle formation (myotubes precursor to actual muscles fiber forms in 7 week of development). Page: 1880 (first bone to ossify in cs18 (day 44 since conception)). Eyes: The Timing and Sequence of Events in the Development of the Human Eye and Ear During the Embryonic Period Proper (search this study, it givers observed details and developments of eye) to summarize at stage 17 (41 since conception) retina have 2 layer filled with precursor nerve cell) and it starts to differentiate after stage 17 which day 41 to 43.

Ears: langsman embryology 15th edition book: page 357 (spiral corti differentiate in 7th week of development) spiral corti is primary structure of the ear for hearing. And also you can look up carniage stage 18 in Google to see how external ear also forms after day 44. Skin: Keith Moore embryology 11th edition page 1001, tells by week 8 to 11 there is new skin stem cells starts that eventually replaces the embryonic skin and becomes the real skin.

I am in medical field. And it's easy for me access these books. But you do your own research. Even if we don't have the reference for it. Or let's say skin or eye or ear starts forming before day 42 or 40: those structure gets their maturity after day 40. Anything before day 40 falls under precursor (getting gathered), and after day 40 angels shape, place in its right place, create its final form. Of course as someone medical field you would be like these getting development by itself. Well angels are metaphysical, maybe they are driving the cell to maturity, or creating new proteins

You said you are in medical field.Can you please help me about bone and flesh mentioned in Quran.? It states first bones form then it covers with flesh

The verse 23:13-14 don't even refer to any sequence of when flesh was created. Rather it says, Allah creates the bone in mudgha (can be understood as unformed embryo body/tissues) and those bones get covered with flesh. And word laham  can means skin, fat, muscles etc.. it's not sequence of creation. Sec, no classical scholars ever commented on or understood verse as strict sequence. Another way of understanding could be as bone are ossified and replacing the cartilage the bone gets covered with flesh. And my brother: take these verse holistically rather than science

Allah is saying look at this fluid, with no feature or strength, turn it into clinging thing, to this unformed flesh, to bone gets created on it and bone is covered. When I read this verse I see more of Allah power to turn the semen into something that no can imagine. So rather then reading as this scientific miracle or some science book read more holistically. Also, remember quran is timeless, it was for ppl of 7th century and 13th century and 24th century and for till end of time. So the real miracle is no matter which era this can be understood without it being an error.

Sorry لحم (laham doesn't mean skin) rather muscles tissue, flesh etc.

Yes thank you very much.I asked this Question because I have heard many people saying bones and flesh form simultaneously.But I also read some medical books,but I found nowhere this type of claim.I don't understand why some people still think that bones and flesh form simultaneously.Do these people ever read any medical books?

Yes bone and muscles does form in similar time frame. It's not like body is completely muscle then bone forms or vise versa. Its like bone and muscles work together in thier formation. But the verse is not talking about formation of muscles rather muscle covering the bone. So myscle forming before, or after or same time as bone is not problem for us.

Actually I am also talking about covering not forming in my comments because In Quran it states first bones then it covered with flesh

I guess people only focus on forming and miss the important part that it is talking about covering(Fa kasawna) not forming(fa khalaqna)
